# How can I wait for an external file function to finish then continue on main?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have main.js and load.js, in load.js there are 2 crucial functions, getData which is an AJAX post call and constHTML which appends data based on the JSON array returned from the AJAX call. This data is appended to a div that will become a carousel slider when I call carousel() on main.js, therefore, It's important to append the data before the carousel() function else the slider renders for 0 items.

> **load.js**

```
var getData = function (item, id) {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax options,
        success: function (data) {
            constHTML(item, data);
        }
    });
}

var constHTML = function (item, data) {
    if (condition) {
        for (var i in data.results) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
    else if (condition) {
        //Do something
    }
}

var getID = function () {
    //Code...
};
```

> **main.js**

```
//Execute getData scripts
if (condition) {
    getData('single', getID());
} else if (condition){
    getData('list', getID());
}

var carousel() = function(){
    //do stuff
}

//call carousel() MUST execute after constHTML in load.js is done
carousel();
```

> **HTML**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/load.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
```

So the result of the above code is load.js loads then main.js loads, getData() is called, ajax call started THEN carousel() executed, constHTML and so on. 
**What I'm trying to do is wait until constHTML() is finished THEN continue to carousel();**. *I cant figure out how to implement deferred objects and promise for cross-file functions.*

Comment: I couldn't find a question on here similar to this (for multiple .js files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **getData** must return the ajax call in order to use [.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks )](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
var getData = function (item, id) {
    return $.ajax({
        //ajax options,
        success: function (data) {
            constHTML(item, data);
        }
    });
}

getData(....).then(
     function() {
       alert( "succeeded" );
     }, function() {
       alert( "failed!" );
     }
 );
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much.